# Is it possible to return pointers to structs in go shared libraries?

Tags: go, cgo

I'm experimenting with using Go for creating dlls in Windows that I can import into Python but I'm having some issues with exporting functions that return a pointer to a Go struct. The following is a very stripped down example:

```
package main

import "C"

type data struct {
    value1, value2 int
}

type PData *data

//export Callme
func Callme() PData {
    var d PData = new (data)
    return d
}

//export getValue1
func getValue1 (st PData) int {
   return st.value1
}

func main() {
}
```

Note I also create a pointer type hoping this would end up as a simple handle on the C side. For the C side to access the struct I would provide helper routines (I provide one example) on the go side that would take a pointer to the struct as an argument. Unfortunately, the above code doesn't compile:

```
go build -o main.dll -buildmode=c-shared .\main.go
# command-line-arguments
.\main.go:5:11: Go type not supported in export: struct {
     value1, value2 int
}
.\main.go:5:11: Go type not supported in export: struct {
    value1, value2 int
}
.\main.go:5:11: Go type not supported in export: struct {
    value1, value2 int
}
.\main.go:5:11: Go type not supported in export: struct {
    value1, value2 int
}
```

Is this a limitation of Go? I've tried simple return values such as int and floats and they work ok.

Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-C_references_to_Go:

> Go struct types are not supported; use a C struct type.

Also check out the following Github issue:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18412

Comment: That's what I feared. I think I can get around it by mapping the go pointers to simple integers which I can return to the C side and used as a handle. I'm thinking there won't be any side effects from the garbage collector.